# TJvHidDeviceController "DevicePath" always showing "\"

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, hid

I'm using TJvHidDeviceController class to retrive HID Device information. I have plugged two HID devices, but i'm trying to ge the "DevicePath" of SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A structure always getting the device path as '\'. So Ican't open CreateFile function. Please help me to solve this issue. My OS win7.
Thanks All.

Comment: If you run your application with full admin rights does the problem persists? Did you use a newer version of Delphi where Char is equal to WideChar instead of AnsiChar?

Comment: Which Delphi version? Which Windows version?

Comment: @Jeroen: In another question user602714 said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895179/how-to-programmatically-change-tablet-pc-orientation (I'm using Delphi 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is guessing!

The one thing I can think of is:

TJvHidDeviceController calls a Windows API call WITHOUT using an A or W suffix. The structure used is SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A, the ANSI version. Now, if you use Delphi 2009 or higher, the routine will expect SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_W. size is the same so everything looks OK. But the strings stored will be USC2 encoded (WideChars) instead of ANSI encoded -> thus after every ANSI character there will be a null byte. TJvHidDeviceController probably converts the character array back to a pascal string using a function like StrPas and hence, you only see the first character.

Check:
Set a breakpoint just after the function call that fills the structure and use the CPU window to view the content as a memory dump. If you see ANSI characters every other  byte and null bytes in between, you can confirm that the above scenario is the case.

Solution:

1. Check if the call is using the wide variant and change the structure accordingly.
2. Check if the call is using the wide variant and use the A variant instead. This is probably the easiest option.

Comment: It's not only guessing. He hasn't said if he's using unicode Delphi (2009+) or some older Ansi delphi version.

Comment: @Warren: that's just part of the guess ;-).

Comment: Hi All, Yes, I'm using Delphi2010. I changed suffix "A" to "W". now its working fine. Now getting all HID device information. Thanks very much. Its help me a lot. Thanks once again...:)